# cURL: POST request gets treated as GET

Tags: php, post, curl, get

I made a POST request, printed out header out information and noticed that is gets treated as GET. What is the reason for such behaviour?

HEADER OUT DATA:

```
GET /inx/aeGDrYQ HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3
Accept: */*
Cookie: PHPSESSID=t762fd0nbi12p3hrgb9sgx9k20; ____ri=4485; safemode=1; session=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%3D; toastMsg=2; ts1=11e2bb0a86bfb9669c36Xcc407e1e3b3decefcce
```

REST OF THE CODE:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://example.com/login');

$postData = [
    'name'       => $name,
    'pass'       => $pass
];

$postDataStr = http_build_query($postData);

# Append some fields to the CURL options array to make a POST request. I left out headers, since
# they don't change and added return_transfer for echoing end results
$options[CURLOPT_POST] = 1;
$options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $postDataStr;
$options[CURLOPT_HEADER]=1;
$options[CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR]=$cookie;
$options[CURLOPT_USERAGENT]= $useragent;


$options[CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION] = true;
$options[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = true;
$options[CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT] = true;

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

# Execute
$response = curl_exec($ch);
// echo $response;

$request = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
echo "Request sent: $request<br>";
```

Comment: is `url_setopt_array` something you do, or just a typo and should be `curl_opt_array`. And note that since you've turned on `followlocation`, curl **WILL** honor 30x redirects, which means the redirected url will be fetched as a `GET`.

Comment: C got lost when copy pasting the code. sorry about that :) So you are saying: turn off followlocation and you will be able to send data with POST?

Comment: Try putting quotes around the $options keys, otherwise it might be treating them as constants.

Comment: no. you are sending with post, but almost certainly that url is issuing a 30x redirect `"Location: /inx/..."`, which curl is following.

Comment: @aynber: -1. totally false. they **ARE** constants, and that's what curl's array function expects.

Comment: @MarcB Ah. I've never used that function. I sit corrected.

Comment: Are you possibly only showing the last request and there were more than one done? You're following a redirect so the redirect-to request could've been made a GET while the first was still a POST...

Comment: Upon browser login I was indeed redirected. First a post and than a get. So header out is only showing the latter of these two.  Thanks guys. Be sure to post solutions as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only showing one request, and I suspect it is the second request where the first was a POST and the GET you see here is the one done after a redirect has been followed.

curl *may* switch to a GET when following a redirect based on which 30x code is in the response and the behavior is guided by the HTTP 1.1 spec (RFC 7230 and friends).